# Separate local repository for different working copies (code bases)

Tags: java, maven

I have a requirement where I have to work on different versions of a project. I am using maven-3.2.5 and right now I have only one local repository which I configured in my settings.xml like this

```
<localRepository>D:/Repo</localRepository>
```

and I have profile like this

```
<profile>
    <id>RepositoryConfig</id>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>public</id>
            <url>http://bxus:8081</url>
        </repository>
        </repositories> 
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>public</id>
            <url>http://bxus:8081</url>
        </pluginRepository>     
    </pluginRepositories>
</profile>
```

As I already told I have to work on different releases so I need to maintain the different code bases. I want to maintain separate local repository for each code base. One way is to create separate settings.xml for each code base but that method I don't want to adopt. I want to do this by one settings.xml file.

Please share your suggestions. I am using elipse as IDE.

Comment: Wouldnt git branches be a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should use multiple branches to track the differences between the versions. In order to share the bulk of the code. See [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/) an introduction to git branches.

If you are using multiple **disconnected** local repositories you will very likely end up in a nightmare. Because you will have to replicate the changes from one repo to another.

Using a single repo with multiple branches will allow you to share the code and maintain only the differences in their own separate branch.

If you need multiple local copies, you can clone the same repo in multiple locations but switch eac one to a different branch.

Then in each branch you are able to use a different maven configuration, if needed, like others have suggested. But the answer is to use multiple branches.

Comment: Agree with your suggestion but here I don't have control over the Git system. It's a short term work and only local setup is required. That's why I want to go with multiple profile logic because it's fitting with my requirement.

Comment: You can create multiple banches locally only, if that is needed. Even if it is something temporarily I won't suggest using multiple disconnected copies. Doing that will only make you lose changes and generate a lot of headache.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use   maven.repo.local :

    1.(repo1) mvn -Dmaven.repo.local= /dir/myrepository1 -DRepositoryConfig1 clean install 

    2.(repo2) mvn -Dmaven.repo.local= /dir/myrepository2 -DRepositoryConfig2 clean install 

And 
<profile>
    <id>RepositoryConfig1</id>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>public</id>
            <url>http://bxus:8081</url>
        </repository>
        </repositories> 
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>public</id>
            <url>http://bxus:8081</url>
        </pluginRepository>     
    </pluginRepositories>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>RepositoryConfig2</id>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>public</id>
            <url>http://bxus2:8081</url>
        </repository>
        </repositories> 
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>public</id>
            <url>http://bxus2:8081</url>
        </pluginRepository>     
    </pluginRepositories>
</profile>
```